# Linq distinct operation

Tags: c#, linq

List `table` contains duplicating elements, how to improve this situation and copy data without duplicates in new list `employee` using linq?

For example output must be something like:

```
List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
employee.Add(new Employee
    {
        Name = "Jhon",
        components = new List<Component>
        {
            new Component { id = "4", work = "clear" },
            new Component { id = "10", work = "load" },
            new Component { id = "5", work = "convert"},
         }
     });
```

But how to do it using linq?

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Table> table = new List<Table>();
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Jhon", id = "4", work = "clear" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Jhon", id = "10", work = "load" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Jhon", id = "5", work = "convert" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Nick", id = "2", work = "load" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Nick", id = "7", work = "load" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Nick", id = "9", work = "load" });
    }
}

public class Empoloyee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Component> components { get; set; }
}
public class Component
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string work { get; set; }
}
public class Table
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string id { get; set; }

    public string work { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are looking for?  None of those objects look like duplicates to me.

Comment: Do you mean a name should only appear once?

Comment: Define `Uniqueness`.

Comment: Absolutely unrelated, but I have an itch to point it out... `Empoloyee` should probably be `Employee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want have components grouped by employ name

```
        List<Table> table = new List<Table>();
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Jhon", id = "4", work = "clear" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Jhon", id = "10", work = "load" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Jhon", id = "5", work = "convert" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Nick", id = "2", work = "load" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Nick", id = "7", work = "load" });
        table.Add(new Table { Name = "Nick", id = "9", work = "load" });

        var employee =  table.GroupBy(t => t.Name)
            .Select(g => new Empoloyee() {Name = g.Key, components = g.Select(t => new Component {id = t.id, work = t.work} ).ToList()})
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This LINQ statement will generate the output you want:

```
List<Empoloyee> employee = table
    .GroupBy(t => t.Name)
    .Select(t => new Empoloyee() { 
        Name = t.Key, 
        components = t.Select(s => new Component() { 
            id = s.id, 
            work = s.work 
        })
        .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: But how to copy elements(id,work) in employee that was related with Names in previous table?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Grouping on Name.

```
var results = table.GroupBy(t=>t.Name)
            .Select( s=> new Empoloyee() {
                Name = s.Key,
                components= s.Select(c=> new Component() { id = c.id, work = c.work}).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R1V6Xy)